# iPhone - Correct use of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm a little confused as to how I should be using `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Without using datasources (keeping things simple),if you display a list of names with `UITableView` and all you want to do is select a name and return it to whatever parent view controller created the `UITableView` list.. what would you do?

I'm used to Windows MFC programming where you have a dialog class and you call `DoModal()` to display the dialog and then query member variables of that dialog object to get the results.. With iPhone programming I'm confused with the whole paradigm. I push the `UITableView` into action, but at what point should I try and retrieve the results? `pushViewController` is asynchronous in nature isn't it? So I can't expect to retrieve results on the line immediately following the pushViewController method?

I'm using `NSMutableArray`s of `NSString`s to keep things simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The patter you are going to use is called `delegation`, what happens is that you call the new `ViewController` and let it do its work, the function that called this will return normally,

Now you need to implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and get the `selectedRow`, after this you will need to return the selected index or value to the original view controller( this will be recieved in another function) please read more about @protocol and delegateion

Comment: Yeah Omar, this is where I get confused. The didSelectRowAtIndexPath method for me is being called within the child UITableViewController and tells me which row etc. The bit I am struggling with is getting that information back to the parent. Surely I would have to pop my child UITableView but somehow return something back to the parent.. but at which point the parent picks it up from again, I have no idea. At present both parent and child are UITableViews so in the parent I push the child ..

Comment: UITableView within the parent's didSelectRowAtIndexPath but it returns immediately after pushViewController (confirmed with breakpoint) so I can't retrieve the child's selection at that point.

Comment: This is a common issues with people that move from Windows or/and MFC, i was like this when i started iOS what you will have to do is to read some documents about delegation pattern and iOS protocols, this will seem like strage at the beginning but once you get used to it it will become easier and easier (currently am in love with it :) )

Comment: OK. Sounds like I will have to go read some of my books on my other Mac.. :) I've just read that I can of course give the child a pointer to the "calling parent" prior to pushing the view.. but you're right.. I feel I'm not fully understanding the intended way of doing things.. so sure, I could hack it to make it work but would benefit more from learning "the right way". :) Thanks.

Comment: @SparkyNZ i used to hack for the first 6 month then i hit a wall :D, dont do my same mistakes and good luck :)